# Streetname/number sorting in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to fill a database with streetnames and numbers.
I have to do it for one city  and I have a list full with streetnames in this format:

streetname 1

streetname 2

streetname 3

streetname 4

streetname 5a

streetname 20

streetname 22

streetname 24

streetname 27

streetname 29b

streetname 33

etc.

Now I need to get the data in this format:

streetname 1-5 A

streetname 20-24 E

streetname 27-29 O

streetname 33 O

O ist for odd e for even and a for all

as you can see it needs to be formatted in an ascending order but it needs to be also fixed if there's a break in the streetnumbers.
Some numbers also contain letters from a to c at the end

By now I  just have some basic code to read in my .txt file
with buffered reader, save the text input in an array list and use some regex to give output in console.

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.DataInputStream;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.regex.Matcher;
        import java.util.regex.Pattern;

        public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String[] arr= null;
                String[] hn=null;

                List<String> strassen = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> hausnummern = new ArrayList<String>();
                String endstr1 = "a";
                String endstr2 = "b";
                String endstr3 = "c";
                String strhn[] = null;
                int hn2;
                try 
                { 
                    FileInputStream fstream_strassen = new FileInputStream("Straßen.txt"); 
                    DataInputStream data_input = new DataInputStream(fstream_strassen); 
                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data_input)); 
                    FileInputStream fstream_strassen2 = new FileInputStream("Straßen.txt"); 
                    DataInputStream data_input2 = new DataInputStream(fstream_strassen2); 
                    BufferedReader buffer2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data_input2)); 

                    String str_line; 
                    String str_line2;

                        while (((str_line = buffer.readLine()) != null) && ((str_line2 = buffer2.readLine()) != null) ) 
                        {                       
                            str_line = str_line.trim(); 
                            str_line2 = str_line2.trim();                       

                            if ((str_line.length()!=0) && (str_line2.length()!=0))  
                            { 
                                strhn = str_line2.split("\\D+");
                                strassen.add(str_line);
                                hausnummern.add(str_line2);                         
                            } 
                        }                   

                    hausnummern.toString();
                    hn = (String[])hausnummern.toArray(new String[hausnummern.size()]);
                    arr = (String[])strassen.toArray(new String[strassen.size()]);              
                }
                catch (Exception e)  
                {
                 // Catch exception if any
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }           

       for(String s : arr) {
                        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(.*?) (\\d*?[a-zA-Z]{0,}?)$").matcher(s);
                        if(m.matches()) {       
                            if(m.group(2).endsWith(endstr1)||m.group(2).endsWith(endstr2)||m.group(2).endsWith(endstr3)==true){
                                hn2 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2).substring(0, m.group(2).length()-1));

                                    if(m.group(2).endsWith(endstr1) == true){

                                        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", m.group(1), hn2, endstr1);
                                        /*if(hn2 % 2 != 0){
                                            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", str, hn2, endstr1);
                                        }*/
                                    }
                                    if(m.group(2).endsWith(endstr2) == true){

                                        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", m.group(1), hn2, endstr2);
                                        /*if(hn2 % 2 != 0){
                                            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", str, hn2, endstr2);
                                        }*/
                                    }
                                    if(m.group(2).endsWith(endstr3) == true){

                                        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", m.group(1), hn2, endstr3);
                                        /*if(hn2 % 2 != 0){
                                            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", str, hn2, endstr3);
                                        }*/
                                    }                           
                            }
                            else{
                                 hn2 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
                                 System.out.printf("%s %s\n", m.group(1), hn2);
                            }
                        }   
                  }
        }
    }
```

My output looks like:

Ihmenkampsweg 1

Ihmenkampsweg 2 a

Ihmenkampsweg 2 b

Ihmenkampsweg 4

Ihmenkampsweg 5

Ihmenkampsweg 9

Ihmenkampsweg 10 a

Ihmenkampsweg 10 b

Ihmenkampsweg 11

Ihmenkampsweg 12 a

Ihmenkampsweg 12 b

Ihmenkampsweg 14 a

Ihmenkampsweg 14 b

Ihmenkampsweg 16 a

Ihmenkampsweg 16 b

Ihmenkampsweg 18

Ihmenkampsweg 20

Now I need help to sort the whole list. Just like in the example above the program should output:

Ihmenkampsweg 1 O

Ihmenkamsweg 2-4 E

Ihmenkampsweg 5 O

Ihmenkampsweg 9-11 O

Ihmenkampsweg 12-20 E

So it needs to be sorted in ascending order, by odd and even and if it's ongoing
I thought about something like splitting up streetname and number and to prove if it's odd or not I could test it with: if(number%2 != 0) it's odd if not it's even number.

But I don't know how to sum up all odd, even and or all streets in a row.
Maybe I could do a loop where it test if streetname is the same like before and number +2 is equal to the next number in array.
I hope somebody could help me with some actual code im stuck on this for a few days ;(

Comment: this question is a pain to read. List the input that the program is expecting, the desired results and what the program has generated so far.

I've no clue what you mean by _"Now i need help to sort the whole list in the way its needed."_

Comment: I agree with Samuel, please format (correctly) the code in your question, and clarify what your issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your inquiry i just updated the code and some text, hope u understand my question. I got a few examples for what my input looks like and what my output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know why but the edit f-up some of your code)

You're asking for help so I'm just gonna give you some advice:

- Create a data structure for your street (a `Street` class which contains the streetname, the street number and the letter, and if it's odd/even if you want)
- Create an `ArrayList` of `Street` and add each street (instead of printing them like you're curently doing). You might want to try to work with `ArrayList` rather than arrays, it's cleaner.
- Be sure to have your list ordered ( search `Array.sort(...)` and `Comparator` for this ). If you're sure it's already ordered, then don't bother.
- Now for the main part: Loop on your `Street ArrayList`: save the first one in a variable, then continue looping and on the next compare the numbers: test if it's the same street and the same number range. Loop like that until the test fails (different street/number range) then print the street first number and last number. Repeat this for each street range.

Do this first, then you can handle the case of odds/even streets being printed. If it's hard, simplify it, don't take a/b/c into account, juste streetname and number, then you can go back and test with streetletters. After that you should also check if there is only one street in a range (for example add `Ihmenkampsweg 50 b` to your test case).